# blocked by CORS policy: react js app issue. Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cors

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/flower' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to` preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.*

ONLY ADDING THE CORS ANYWHERE PREURL IT WORKS FOR 10 TIMES, AS IT IS TEMPORAY. HOW DO I FIX THIS ?

SCREENSHOT:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvSmE.png

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
function App() {

  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  const [meanings, setMeanings] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("en");

  const dictionaryApi = async () => {
    try {
      const app_id = "6a94204f";
      const app_key = "953e41694cf8d1bf1549b3fcec957f5c";
      const data = await axios.get(
        // `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/flower`
        `https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/flower`


        , {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': '6a94204f',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization",
          }
        });

      setMeanings(data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  console.log(meanings);

  useEffect(() => {
    dictionaryApi();
  }, [word, category]);



  return <>HELLO</>;
}
```

export default App;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS related issues should be commonly solved from server side.

Please try using Postman or similar app to trigger GET request URL https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/flower.

When I try, it shows 'Authentication parameters missing'.

Maybe you are not making correct use of app_id and app_key in axios request.

## Edit with update as follows.

Authorization header is not required here. It is app_id and app_key should be supplied in header to make it work. You can refer a documentation available here https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/

Above issue is not related to CORS at all. I have tried it in Postman and it is found working.

There are few suggestions though

1. **Because you have already shared your app_key and app_id here, do take care and delete / deactivate existing app_key and generate new one. This will avoid misuse of your app_key because sharing it here have already exposed this key to public.**
2. Using API Key and App Id directly in react will make it accessible to client side / frontend. If you have server side / backend then create a separate API endpoint with JWT like secure authentication and use it instead.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
function App() {

  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  const [meanings, setMeanings] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("en");

  const dictionaryApi = async () => {
    try {
      const app_id = "<your app id here>";
      const app_key = "<your app key here>";
      const data = await axios.get(
        // `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/flower`
        `https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/flower`
        , {
          headers: {
            'app_id': app_id, //<-- add app id here
            'app_key': app_key, //<-- add app key here
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization",
          }
        });

      setMeanings(data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  console.log(meanings);

  useEffect(() => {
    dictionaryApi();
  }, [word, category]);
```

I have tried the same using Postman and I have exported it for axios

```js
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/flower',
  headers: { 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization', 
    'Origin': 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com', 
    'app_id': '<app_id>', 
    'app_key': '<app_key>'
  }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, how to set the API key and ID in axios then ? I tried multiple different things, it never worked for me.

Comment: I am referring to this page. https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/
Hopefully it should be correct.
You can pass app_id and app_key in header

Comment: I have updated my answer to show a way to use app_key and app_id.